# Removing a reference to System.Web.Mvc 2

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dll-reference

Visual Studio 2010
Asp.Net Web Project (this is not mvc project)

I have a kentico CMS web project that i have just upgraded to new version. This new version uses System.Web.Mvc 3. I need to remove System.Web.Mvc 2 reference. I am not seeing this reference in Bin folder, so how can i remove Mvc 2 reference?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of this reference you're seeing, and of the "References" node in Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

i have removed the reference from web.config, assemblies section